# JQM (jQueryMobile) Access to URL history?

Tags: jquery, ajax, history, jquery-mobile

I have a issue with being able to link back to the home page from a AJAX response from a Multi-page layout form submission

The structure

`index.php` has multi-page agreement (`index.php#agreement`)

`#agreemen`t has a form that is using the default AJAX call for submission to (`agreement.php`)

From agreement.php I can go back to the last page (`#agreement`) which is expected but now I wanted to go back to the `index.php` page.

I can easily put `href="index.php"` but then the session looses it values.

Is there a way to go back two steps? or access the URL history and point to a specific page without loosing any of the data in the form(s)?

I have binded `agreement.php` using this code in `index.php`

```
$('#agreement_status').live('pageshow',function(event, ui){
    // Button action
    $('#back_home').click(function(){
        window.history.back(); // this goes back one page to index.php#agreement
        window.history.back(-2); // this goes back one page to index.php#agreement
        $.mobile.changePage("#index", "slideup"); // this works but appends the hashtag in the URL which breaks the other functionality 
    });
});
```

In `agreement.php` I have this code

```
<a id="back_home" 
   data-role="button" 
   data-icon="home" 
   data-theme="z" 
   data-inline="true" 
   style="float:right;">
    Home
</a>
```

Comment: I am currently having a similar issue with changePage, where it redirects correctly, but leaves a hashtag in the URL which breaks everything. I will let you know if I find a way to fix it.

Comment: They just released ver a4 so I will be testing with that soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is not really an answer to my question but it did solve my problem:

agreement.php back button code, use the data-rel="back" option in the anchor tag and add a div tag with name/id agreement_status

```
<a data-rel="back" 
   data-role="button" 
   data-icon="home" 
   data-theme="z" 
   data-inline="true" 
   style="float:right;">
    Home
</a>
```

In the index.php page, add this to your java script

```
$('#agreement_status').live('pagehide',function(event, ui){
    window.history.back();
});
```

What happen is the pagehide fires when the agreement_status page is hidden, so you will be on the #agreement page. Then with window.history.back(); we are able to go back to the index.php page and still keep all the data in tacked without the need for a refresh of the page

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        window.location.href = "/index.php";
```

Comment: this just redirects and I would loose any URL parameters as well as any data that has been entered not saved